# Select rows which has multiple values in junction table

Tags: postgresql, junction-table

I have three tables:

```
posts (id, content)
posts_tags (posts_id, tags_id)
tags (id, tag)
```

How do I select all posts that have (at least) 2 specific tags (lets say tags with id 1 and 2)?

For example, posts table:

```
  id   content   
 ---- ------- 
  1    post1  
  2    post2  
  3    post3
```

tags table:

```
  id   tag   
 ---- ------ 
  1    tag1  
  2    tag2  
  3    tag3
```

posts_tags table:

```
  posts_id   tags_id  
 ---------- --------- 
  1          1        
  1          2        
  2          1        
  3          1        
  3          2        
  3          3
```

I then expect the following result:

```
  id   content  
 ---- --------- 
  1    post1    
  3    post3
```

Post with ID 3 (since it has tags 1, 2, and 3) and post with id 1 (since it has tags with id 1, and 2) but not post 2 since it doesn't have tag with id 2.

Assume I can not change the table structure.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question:

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.posts_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.tags_id
WHERE tags.id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p
JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.posts_id = p.id
WHERE pt.tags_id IN (1,2);


SELECT * 
FROM posts p
JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.posts_id = p.id
WHERE pt.tags_id = 1 OR pt.tags_id = 2;


SELECT * 
FROM posts p
JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.posts_id = p.id
WHERE pt.tags_id = 1 AND pt.tags_id = 2;
```

**EDIT:** Quick and dirty

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT  pt.posts_id AS post, 
    p.content AS content, 
    STRING_AGG(pt.tags_id::TEXT,',') AS agg
FROM posts p
JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.posts_id = p.id
GROUP BY pt.posts_id, p.content
)
SELECT post,content
FROM j
WHERE STRING_TO_ARRAY(agg,',') @> ('{2,1}'::TEXT[])
```

Comment: I may have been unclear. This will also select posts that have only one of the tags.

Comment: Just added  a second option with `OR` and `AND` to my answer

Comment: I think OR will be functionally equivalent to the IN example and the AND will never return any rows since no rows have multiple tag ids.

Comment: Last try.. I just added an example using CTE :-)